# How to join a LAN / IPX game on Diablo 1?

Tags: networking, diablo

Recently some of my friends and I grew nostalgic about the original Diablo and realized we've never truly tried the multiplayer aspect of that game. So we set up a modern VPN LAN solution via tuungle (using the appropriate IPX Wrappers) but the problem is, while any of us can manage to create session in Diablo FULL, others cannot find a way to join my IPX/LAN game.

**There are no "join" buttons in the game itself.**

I've read somewhere that Spawn version is a trial version but can be used to join Multiplayer games. If they can, is it possible for them to play the entire game on LAN or is trial restricted from choosing some classes/accessing some areas?

Or are there some other ways to join?

Comment: Is there some actual reason you're not just using the classic Battle.net? You won't even need a second copy of the game, as you should be able to use the spawn feature (just make sure you patch the game as well).

Comment: For some reason, connection to B.NET is very shaky from where we live. LAN is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest version of Diablo for all players. [Download here](http://www.fileplanet.com/60311/60000/fileinfo/Diablo-Patch-v1.09) or through Battle.net.
2. Set up [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) for an artificial connection.
3. I forget whether you use Direct Cable Connect or LAN, from here, but connecting should be straightforward with no hitches if you have everything set up properly.

Spawn versions are only allowed to play the Warrior class.

If you find the game too easy in a serious group, I recommend checking out [Cave-in Ironman](http://thedsfcommunity.yuku.com/topic/2284/IRONMAN-BASIC-RULES-CAVEIN-RULES-AND-QUESTIONS#.Ue-INNIp9Mg) where you and friends try to complete the game without returning to town. It's a ton of fun.

Comment: Anyone know if battle.net is still up for Diablo 1 in 2017?

Comment: @KolobCanyon As of sometime around March 2018, Diablo 1 games cannot be created or joined on Battle.net.

Comment: But don't fret. There's a mobile diablo game.... yay?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this and with the IPX wrappers I was only able to get 2 players going at a time. On attempting to get a 3rd player into the IPX LAN the game would crash. The only way I was able to get it working was to actually build 4 winxp virtual machines in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)  and install the actual IPX protocol on each.

Virtualbox is also great because even though the resolution of the game is only 640 X 480 virtualbox allows you to stretch the 640 x 480 resolution to whatever your native screen resolution is.